# Httperf Configuration

Tags: javascript, httperf

I want to configure httperf in a way that it wait for page to load all attached files. In my case, there are 2 Javascript files which are attached with this page.
What should its command in this case. 
I am trying with this command but could not succeed.

httperf --server 40.25.296.121 --port 7001 --uri /com.tele/addperson.html --rate 150 --num-conn 27000 --num-call 1 --timeout 5.

Is it possible with this tool?

Answer (score 1):

You may try the option --print-reply [header|body] to print the reply content and see if the js files is loaded. But httperf is not a browser so it won't render the js scripts.